# JPEG Error when opening image downloaded in Python

Tags: python, image, python-requests

So using the Requests library in python I attempted to download an image

[image]

This is my code:

```
import requests
add = "https://www.bigbasket.com/media/uploads/p/s/20001190_10-fresho-onion.jpg"
img = requests.get(add)
open("img.jpg", 'wb').write(img.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

But when I open the image I just downloaded I get this error:

[image: Error on opening image]

But when I do the same thing with a simple wget command I get valid results:

```
wget 'https://www.bigbasket.com/media/uploads/p/s/20001190_10-fresho-onion.jpg'
--2018-06-15 11:25:14--  
https://www.bigbasket.com/media/uploads/p/s/20001190_10-fresho-onion.jpg
Resolving www.bigbasket.com (www.bigbasket.com)... 104.122.2.43
Connecting to www.bigbasket.com (www.bigbasket.com)|104.122.2.43|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3653 (3.6K) [image/jpeg]
Saving to: ‘20001190_10-fresho-onion.jpg’
20001190_10-fresho-onion.jpg         100% 

[====================================================================>]   
3.57K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2018-06-15 11:25:14 (215 MB/s) - ‘20001190_10-fresho-onion.jpg’ saved 
[3653/3653]
```

This is the image downloaded by wget.

[image: Working Image]

I've checked to see if the response was a bot-blocker or if my request was forbidden or something else but I get a valid binary string that I'm guessing must represent an image.

I think this has something to do with the 'utf-8' encoding that I'm doing but I can't quite get a handle on what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `img.content` instead of `img.text.encode()`.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that; It works thanks a bunch @Aran-Fey